# how to integrate converge Elavon in ios with using apple pay in obj-c?

Tags: ios, applepay

I have integrated apple pay in ios (iPhone,obj-c).

but how can i test Apple pay ,is there any demo credit card with some amount to pay some money?

Comment: I hope you will get info here https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/

Answer (score 0):

For testing Apple pay in demo mode you can use Sandbox environment. Card numbers are available in the below Apple website [Test Cards for Apps and the Web](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/)

Additionally:
The [Braintree documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/client-side/ios/v4) might hep you, please take a look.